# What are the chances for Storm Nimbus's effects?

Tags: titan-quest-anniversary-edition

What are the chances for Storm Nimbus's effects?

It's been said in a [Steam Discussion](https://steamcommunity.com/app/475150/discussions/0/2425614539580561722/#c1488866180606361404):

> "X% chance of one of the following" in this game means equal chance of the following which add up to X%. For example if it says "30% chance of one of the following" and there are 3 lines below it, the actual chance would be 10% for each line. If there is no "X%", then X=100%.

So, each time I attack with anything, there's a 100% chance of some effect, and a 50% chance of it being Ice or Lightning Damage added to my attack? Since there's two effects and at least one of them must happen?

Answer (score 1):

While we cannot answer the question definitively without a developer reply, or diving into the actual code, you are correct in assuming that there is always a 100% chance of some effect.

I think it's safe to assume that either effect will have an equal chance of appearing, as that seems to be the consensus among the player-base. Either sub-effect will have a 50/50 chance of appearing.